# Find only one element in html page using soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to find with soup just one element in an html page or it's designed to always look for all the elements with same attributes? I have this code below and again I'm choosing ebay because it's handy. I just want to print the first price on the page displayed as an integer in the console. I only get None responses. I tried all the combinations possible for the find function with soup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1312&_nkw=Ryzen+9+3950x&_sacat=0"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
page.close()

price = soup.find("div",href_="https://www.ebay.com/p/10035392721?iid=313304858607#UserReviews", class_= "s-item__price").get_text(strip=True)

print(price)
```

Please show me how do I print one price with soup. Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to find a `div` with an `href`? You probably want the `a` inside a `div` with that `href` - or perhaps you want the `div` that has an `a` inside it with that `href`?

Comment: I tried everything, a included. Still no price shown.

Comment: Your code gets you the first `div` with a `href` that has the specified value. Since no `div` has a `href`, you get `None`. What did you expect to get? The first `div` that has an `a` in it that has that `href`? What did you try to get that?

Comment: show me how you would do it. thanks

Comment: You need to know the basics of HTML if you want to be able to scrape web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first price, see the following example using a CSS Selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1312&_nkw=Ryzen+9+3950x&_sacat=0"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

print(soup.select_one("li:nth-of-type(n+2) span.s-item__price").text)
```

Output:

```
$575.00
```

To get all tags use:

```
for tag in soup.select("li:nth-of-type(n+2) span.s-item__price"):
    print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Thank you MendelG. Awesome.